# Which css framework to choose for angular 2 at this moment?

Tags: css, angular

We reached the decision to use angular2 for building our new application. It is a special type of contacts/tasks manager.
The decision left is which css framework to use.

What i have seen so far is:

Angular Material - version 1 cant be used with Angular 2 and version 2 is not ready yet (and i couldnt find any release roadmap/date)

Material Design Lite - I am not sure how good that one is to use with angular. Or, to put it differently, will our opportunity cost of choosing it over Angular Material 2 be high?

Twitter Bootstrap - this one is last option if first two not used (for whatever reason)

I am also open to any other suggestions.

PS.
It is important for us that it is a well supported one, with active development and good prospect.

Comment: disclaimer: i am well aware that this question might be viewed as opinion based, but the 'at the moment' part is crucial here. my main concern is the current and near future state of the frameworks and other developers experience with them in that sense. that's why i think its not opinion but experience based. tnx

Comment: Opinions born of experience are still opinions, and product recommendations are explicitly off-topic even without being opinionated.

Comment: Ok, i respect that. What about rephrasing it in a way: "which one of the listed frameworks you have least problems with at this moment having on mind current state of development cycles of frameworks and angular2?" Would you still consider that as opinion/recommendation based? tnx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a personal preference what you are asking. 
From my experience, I would go with Bootstrap as it is the most mature of those CSS frameworks you wrote.

Also, Bootstrap already has a lot of great plugins, great documentation, great community and will continue to grow.

I was working with material, and it has a lot of problems since it is still in beta version, and my personal opinion about it that it is not built for the web, but only for mobile. :)

Comment: thank you for the bootstrap insight! also, when you say you worked with material...which one you have on mind? Angular Material or Material Design Lite or both? tnx

Comment: I have worked with Angular Material, but both of those are based on materializecss.com which is in beta.

Comment: in our team, we really do like material design on android and we are strongly considering to use it on web in this application. but on the other hand, i also got impression that it still has alot of problems plus it doesn't feel Angular Material 2 is anywhere near production. and that's where maturity of Bootstrap is a huge plus, for the moment and for foreseeable future.

Answer (score -1):

Which web style you want or feature?

ng Material & Material Design Lite are Material Style , Bootstrap is not

but at your list , they are all has Gird System .

it's useful on Layout (both RWD or normal ) .

and ng2 Component has individual css .

so if you want , you can use css framework combine with ng2

but as I know Bootstrap has ng2 Component . maybe you want to try it

refer : https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/datepicker

or you want ng2 Material

refer : https://justindujardin.github.io/ng2-material/#/